# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier - error in Chrome VM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this pretty simple code, which works but it is returning an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" in Chrome's VM3197:1
What should I do to get rid of it? Code seems ok to me... The only other code I'm running is jQuery and the html5 boilerplate snippet to get rid of console errors in browser who don't support it.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var app = (function () {

        var toggleMenu = function(){
            var $offcanvasMenu = $('.offcanvas');
            $offcanvasMenu.toggleClass('-display');
            setTimeout($offcanvasMenu.toggleClass('-show'), 1000);
        };

        return {
            toggleMenu : toggleMenu
        };

    })();

    $('.icon-bars').on('click', function() {
        app.toggleMenu();
    });

});
```

Comment: That code block looks fine. Are you sure it's that section in particular that's causing the problem?

Comment: Not related: your setTimeout code is incorrect.

Comment: @vinayakj: then there is not much value in mentioning it. Aliasing jQuery to `$` in the ready handler like this is a common pattern.

Comment: When I click on VM nothing is shown. I have rmeoved the wrong setTimeout and the thing is gone though...

Answer (score 4):

In order to get rid of unexpected errors, try to correct Your code's structure.

`setTimeout` expects the first parameter to be a function, so You need an anonymous function here:

```
setTimeout( function(){
    $offcanvasMenu.toggleClass('-show');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: 1) is completely wrong. Please remove it from your post to make a decent answer.

Comment: No it doesn't (you can try yourself). You may want to read [How do JavaScript closures work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/111102/1048572)